# How To Form my Node and Tree Generic Classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have an `IList<Category>`

The Category type is coming from my Category Table in SQL Server:

Table: Category

CategoryID, ParentCategoryID

so typical heirarchy in one table.

So if I have this IList of Categories that contain the node relationships, then I am trying to figure out how this fits into making a Node and Tree like a lot of people are doing.  And how would the constructor look and this class be created in terms of usage?

I think it makes sense here to create a generic Node class and Tree class so I can reuse in the future I think for other tree types.

So if I have something like this, how is T being used and what am I benefiting from?

(pseudo code here)

```
public class Node<T>
...
    Node<T> _parentNode;
    List<Node<T>> _children;

    private void SetParentNode(T)
    private void AddChild(T)

... etc.
```

trying to understand the concept here on why a Generic Node class would be used for any type coming in like Childeren, etc. that contains a child/parent relationship (int Ids)

**UPDATE**

So having an issue here with the GroupBy recommendation.  Check out what I tried to do with your example:

First I have this property in my Tree class:

public Dictionary, IList>> ParentNodeAndRelatedChildrenFlattenedMap { get; private set; }

and incoming to my class's constructor is a IList dependencies that I converted (looped and created a new Node for every one of them) to a IList>

Now I'm trying to group that list by Node.ParentId as you were talking so that I get a grouping on Parent Nodes and since each node has its children property it's easy to find out what the related children are to those parent nodes.

But here is the problem now later down in my code:

```
public void CreateFlattenedMap()
{
    var parentGroups = _nodeDependencies.GroupBy(d => d.ParentNodeId);

    var dictionary = parentGroups.ToDictionary(d => d, d => d.ToList());

    ParentNodeAndRelatedChildrenFlattenedMap = dictionary;
}
```

well it's not liking my assignment of dictionary because it's an > dictionary that's created by the ToDictionary().  So not sure how to get this grouping grouped and to a dictionary that is a , List> where Node in the dictionary is the Node instance for that parent I'm grouping on (yea I'm grouping on its Node.ParentId but I want the Node though in the ToDictionary in the end) and the List> is the list of Children Nodes from the Parent Node.Children property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what a more complete implementation would look like:

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    private T _item;
    private TreeNode<T> _parentNode;
    private List<TreeNode<T>> _children;

    public TreeNode(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public void SetParentNode(T parent)
    {
        _parentNode.Item = parent;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set { _item = value; }
    }

    public void AddChild(T child)
    {
        _children.Add(new TreeNode<T>(child));
    }

    public void RemoveChild(T child)
    {
        var node = _children.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item.Equals(child));
        if (node != null)
            _children.Remove(node);
    }
}
```

And your questions:

**How would the constructor look and this class be created in terms of usage?**

As you can see from the above in `AddChild()`, simply specify the type of the child for the constructor.

```
var node = new TreeNode<T>(item);
```

**So if I have something like this, how is `T` being used and what am I benefiting from?**

The use of generics can same a lot of time rewriting code when done right. In the implementation above, we can make a tree structure out of basically any type we want by simply changing `T`. So this saves us a lot of time if we need a tree structure for more than one type.

```
var intTreeNode = new TreeNode<int>(10);
var stringTreeNode = new TreeNode<string>("hello world");
```

Generically really take some exposure time before it clicks and you "just get it", keep at it.

### Constructing the tree

To construct the tree from a list of categories that may or may not have parent categories you will need to iterate through the list in some way. A decent way to go about this would be to first organise them into groupings based on the `ParentCategoryID` and constructing the tree. Something like this (untested):

```
public List<TreeNode<Category>> ConstructCategories(List<Category> categories)
{
    var groups = categories.GroupBy(e => e.ParentCategoryID);
    var rootGroup = groups.Single(e => e.Key == null);
    var categories = List<TreeNode<Category>>();

    foreach (var category in rootGroup)
    {
        // Create and fill category
        var node = new TreeNode<Category>(category);
        ConstructChildrenCategories(node, groups);
        categories.Add(node);
    }
}

public void ConstructChildrenCategories(TreeNode<Category> node, IEnumerable<IGrouping<Category>> groups)
{
    var group = groups.Single(e => e.Key == node.Item.CategoryID);

    foreach (var category in group)
    {
        // Create and fill category
        var childNode = new TreeNode<Category>(category);
        ConstructChildrenCategories(childNode, groups);

        // We could do this automatically in both methods.
        childNode.SetParent(node.Item);
        node.AddChild(childNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: so here's the thing, thanks bTW.  If I have that list of relationships that have the Category and ParentCategory, where and how would I iterate that list to find a node's children?  I mean when I create a new TreeNode, I need to be able to iterate the main list to find its children...so would I pass the entire IList into my  TreeNode so I can iterate it and add to my TreeNode's children list?

Comment: yea that is what I figured after thinking about this before you updated.  That I'll have to iterate through and create a new node for every row

Comment: so your Single on group just gets those child nodes for this node?

Comment: Yes that's right, I didn't test this or anything though so it may be a little off.

Comment: another thing public class Node<T> where T : ICategory restricts it to one type, category.  I want my node class to be able to take in any type of relationship custom object

Comment: I am using a Dictionary to represent the tree map ultimately as the "tree"

Comment: To take in more than one type they need a common class/interface that they inherit from, ie. `Node<BaseEntity>` or something.

Comment: shouldn't the  SetParentNode method be public?

Comment: Yep, I updated the code. Most of the members should be `public`.

Comment: The underlying object (`T`).

Comment: thanks.  I noticed you are calling ConstructChildrenCategories again when you cycle the single group's nodes and sending in the childnode to the ConstructChildrenCategories....why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27263/discussion-between-daniel-imms-and-coffeeaddict)

Comment: ran into another snag.  Your groupby is causing me some issues in that I'm getting it seems a grouping of int, and related e.  I need it grouped by e, and List<e> so that when I do a ToDictionary it gives me a dictionary of <e, List<e>> where e is the Node<T> not int representing the parent node

Comment: I see your ParentNode in your tree is private so how would an outside caller get it out of your TreeNode instance?

Comment: Expose `ParentNode` like we do for `Item` then.

Answer (score 2):

This may be helpful:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    int Id { get; }
    int ParentId { get; }
}

public class Category : ICategory
{
    int id;
    int parentId;

    public int Id { get { return id; }}
    public int ParentId { get { return parentId; }}
}
```

And this is the `Node` class:

```
public class Node<T> where T : ICategory
{
    Node<T> _parentNode;
    List<Node<T>> _children;

    public Node<T> Parent { get { return _parentNode; }}

    public Node<T> Child(int index) { return _children[index]; }

    public T Value;

    public Node(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public void AddChild(T item)
    {
        Node<T> child = new Node<T>(item);
        this._children.Add(child);
        child._parentNode = this;
    }
}
```

And this is the `Tree` class:

```
public class Tree<T> where T : ICategory
{
    List<Node<T>> values;

    public Tree()
    {
        this.values = new List<Node<T>>();
    }

    public Node<T> FindNode(int id)
    {
        if (values.Exists(input => input.Value.Id == id))
        {
            return values.Find(input => input.Value.Id == id);
        }
        else { return null; }

    }

    public void AddNode(T value)
    {
        Node<T> parent = FindNode(value.ParentId);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.AddChild(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again though public class Tree<T> where T : ICategory and public class Node<T> where T : ICategory is tying those to a specific type expected.  I want any type expected.  The way did that was to create an INode that requires a NodeId and related ParentNodId.  Then I know anything using my node class or tree class has to have a NodeId and ParentNodeId available to work with.

Comment: however you did give me some good ideas on how to find and add nodes so thanks much

Comment: what is  public T Value; what does Value Stand for?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict As you may know, it's a simple field (I know we should not mark fields of a class as `public` but for simplicity I ignore that).

Comment: `Value` doesn't stand for anything. I just use it to save the actual value of the `ICategory` for each node.

Answer (score -1):

You can't make all the function of tree and treenode.

rather add the class data to Treenode.

for example

```
class MyClass
{
    public int A;
    public string B;
}

...

TreeNode Node = TreeView.Nodes.Add("AAA");
MyClass Data = new MyClass();
Node.Tag = Data;
```

The Data assigned to TreeNode will not be deleted. and you can use whole tree property and Nodes member, too.

the only thing that you should do is typecast when use data of the node.

```
TreeNode Node = TreeView.Nodes[0];
MyClass Temp = Node.Tag as MyClass;
```