# How to create a simple generics node tree in c#

Tags: c#, generics, treenode

My task is to make a simple generics node tree in c#. Furthermore, I need to make 3 simple methods... One for adding, the second for removing/deleting nodes and the last one to print them in my console. I was following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697812/how-to-form-my-node-and-tree-generic-classes), but I found a problem with deleting which uses LINQ. Also, it would be nice to get a advise how to make it without LINQ, interfaces etc, just to make it as simple as it can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your example without LINQ:

```
public void RemoveChild(T child)
{
            TreeNode<T> node = null;
            foreach (var childNode in _children)
            {
                if (childNode.Item.Equals(child))
                {
                    node = childNode;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (node != null)
                _children.Remove(node);
}
```